# Contactform 7 cant set hidden value

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to implement the Paypal payment gateway once the contact form is submitted.

For that I am storing the form data in db and retrieving data from the saved id once payment is completed. Saving that db id in hidden field for sending to paypal url.

I have tried and values are returned. But when I getting form data in wpcf7mailsent it is empty.

```
function action_wpcf7_submit( $array ) { 
    global $wpdb;
    
    $wpcf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
    $form_id = $wpcf7->id;
    
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $invalid_fields = $submission->get_invalid_fields();

    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    
    if ($form_id ==123 && empty($invalid_fields))
    {
            $first_name = $posted_data['first-name'];
            $last_name = $posted_data['last-name'];
            $parent_email = $posted_data['parent-email'];
            $parent_phone = $posted_data['parent-phone'];
            $duration = $posted_data['Duration'][0];
            $total_price = $posted_data['total_price'];
            $notes_requests = $posted_data['notes-requests'];
            $studentcount = $posted_data['studentcount'];
            
            $table_name = "store_subscription";
$result_check = $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('parent_guardian_firstname' => $first_name, 'parent_guardian_lastname' => $last_name, 'parent_guardian_email' => $parent_email,'parent_guardian_phone' => $parent_phone, 'subscription_duration' => $duration, 'total_price' => $total_price, 'notes_special_request' => $notes_requests) ); 
$lastid = $wpdb->insert_id; 
            
            if($result_check){   
                for($i=1;$i<=$studentcount;$i++){
                  $add_student_name = $posted_data['student_name_'.$i];
                  $add_current_grade_level = $posted_data['current_grade_level_'.$i];                   
                  $additional_student_table = "store_subscription_student";
                  if(!empty($add_student_name)){                 
                    $wpdb->insert($additional_student_table, array('store_subscription_id'=> $lastid, 'student_name' => $add_student_name, 'grade_level' => $add_current_grade_level)); 
                  }
               }
                
                //setting the store_subscriptin_id to retrieve the data from the paypal.            
            $posted_data['store_subscription_id'] = $lastid;
            $posted_data['paypal_pg_redirect_url'] = "https://www.example.com/redirect-paypal/?id=$lastid&amt=$total_price";
                
                return $posted_data;
             }  
    }
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_submit', 'action_wpcf7_submit');

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );

function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( e ) {
    console.log(e.detail);
if ( '123' == e.detail.contactFormId ) {
    var paypal_pg_redirect_url = document.getElementById('paypal_pg_redirect_url').value;
    console.log(paypal_pg_redirect_url);
     ///window.location.href = paypal_pg_redirect_url;
}
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
```

The hidden field value is not set. Can someone help me to set the hidden field value and retrieve in `wpcf7mailsent`

Note: I have tried hook before_send_mail, later came to know that we cant change the value in before_send_mail. So then I tried posted_data hook also the value not set to hidden field. `store_subscription_id` is the hidden field I am trying to set value. Pls help.

Comment: As I researched and It is not possible I think and I have set in the session and then retrieved that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding `if(isset())` before setting the value:

```
if(isset($lastid)){
    $posted_data['store_subscription_id'] = $lastid;
}
```